# InfoBarMessage set to none in viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, catel

I've used so far some Catel DataWindow specifing in the constructor

```
public class MyViewModel: base(Catel.Windows.DataWindowMode.OkCancel, null, Catel.Windows.DataWindowDefaultButton.None, true, Catel.Windows.InfoBarMessageControlGenerationMode.None)
```

in order to not have the InfoBarMessage and it works perfectly

Now I've a catel:UserControl how can I disable that InfoBarMessage? since I've a Model that validates some filters and I want to have validation on UIElements

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

User controls don't create an InfoBarMessageControl in Catel. If you disable it for all windows, you should set `UserControl.DefaultskipSearchingForInfoBarMessageControl = true;`.

You should also look into [ApiCop](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/ApiCop). It will inform you about best practices based on the actual code you are using at runtime, for example:

```
================================================================
DATAWINDOWTEST.VIEWS.AVIEW
================================================================

Cop TargetType: Catel.Windows.Controls.MVVMProviders.Logic.UserControlLogic
Rule: UserControlLogic.InfoBarMessageControl (Error)
For more information about this rule, visit https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Performance+considerations

[DataWindowTest.Views.AView] Feature used '0' of '2' times, consider turning it off by default

----------------------------------------------------------------

Cop TargetType: Catel.Windows.Controls.MVVMProviders.Logic.UserControlLogic
Rule: UserControlLogic.CreateWarningAndErrorValidator (Error)
For more information about this rule, visit https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Performance+considerations

[DataWindowTest.Views.AView] Feature used '0' of '2' times, consider turning it off by default

----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I've tried to put that line on App.Xaml's OnStartup method but the only one I've found is             UserControl.DefaultSkipSearchingForInfoBarMessageControlValue = true; ...setting it to true doesn't solve my problem by the way..